# Column name Entity Framework base Repository

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, select, repository

**`IRepositoryBase`**

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);
```

**`RepositoryBase`**

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll([OptionalAttribute][DefaultParameterValueAttribute(null)]Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    var set = CreateSet().IncludeMultiple(includes);
    return (predicate == null) ? set : set.Where(predicate);      
}
```

**`IAccountService`**

```
IEnumerable<int> GetAllReferenceIds();
```

**`AccountService`**

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetAllReferenceIds()
{
    var accountOwners = _accountOwnerRepository.GetAll();
    return accountOwners.Select(m => m.ReferenceId).ToList();
}
```

**`AccountController`**

```
public ActionResult ReferenceIdPartial()
{

    ViewData["AccountOwners"] = accountOwnerService.GetAllReferenceIds();

    return PartialView();

}
```

**MVC Partial View** - DevExpress combobox MVC extension

```
settings.Properties.Columns.Add("ReferenceId", "Reference Id", Unit.Percentage(100));
```

Error: `column ReferenceId Not found`

I am sending a collection of `int` through `GetReferenceIds()`.

Is there a way to call the columns from Controller? Something like  `AccountOwner(a=>a.ReferenceIds, select ReferenceIds)`? I should be able to get the column name as well as the data.

Comment: Who does throw the exception "*column ReferenceId Not found*"? The combobox code or does it come from the `GetAllReferenceIds` method?

Comment: Its coming from the combobox. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot into the dark, I actually only understand your last sentence "*I should be able to get the column name as well as the data*" - and could imagine that if you bind a collection to a combobox (I don't know the DevExpress combobox extension) the combobox control wants a collection of *class* objects with a *property name/property value* pair instead of only a collection of values ( `int`). So, without touching the `AccountService` you could try:

```
public ActionResult ReferenceIdPartial()      
{
    ViewData["AccountOwners"] = accountOwnerService.GetAllReferenceIds()
        .Select(i => new { ReferenceId = i });

    return PartialView();
}
```

`ViewData["AccountOwners"]` now would hold a collection of (anonymous) objects. Each object has one property called `ReferenceId` with a value `i` fetched from the Ids you returned from your service.

Comment: Hi Slauma - Thanks for the reply. I am still getting all the columns when I am doing that. And then I am able to get the referenceId column. But I want not get all the columns - Since the number of columns is ~45, it is impacting the speed of the application.

Comment: @tjRulz: But `GetAllReferenceIds` is only returning `IEnumerable<int>`. It's only a list of numbers. How can that contain all columns?

Comment: Hi Slauma. I am sorry. I changed the code at my end before I read you reply. I can then use the above code. Thanks again.